# nodejs, get aws cloudwatch stream list

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I tried to get the cloudwatch stream list, but it seems that the official does not provide the relevant [api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html).
I hope to be able to achieve similar functions, such as obtaining the latest 10 stream logs.

The most similar I see so far is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#getLogEvents-property) api:

```
var params = {
  logGroupName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  time: 'NUMBER_VALUE'
};
cloudwatchlogs.getLogGroupFields(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

But I don't know how to operate the `time` parameter. This parameter is not like iso time format and so on, but the number of seconds?

Because I don’t know when the latest log was generated, time conversion is quite inconvenient. Is there a better way to get the log list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS Per AWS CloudWatchLogs Official SDK [DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html).

**getLogGroupFields**:

> Returns a list of the fields that are included in log events in the
> specified log group, along with the percentage of log events that
> contain each field

I think this [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#describeLogStreams-property) will not help you out to achieve your goal.
As per your requirement use ***describeLogStreams***. Which can do the following thing.

> Lists the log streams for the specified log group. You can list all
> the log streams or filter the results by the prefix. You can also control
> how the results are ordered.

```
var params = {
  logGroupName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  descending: true || false,
  limit: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  logStreamNamePrefix: 'STRING_VALUE',
  nextToken: 'STRING_VALUE',
  orderBy: LogStreamName | LastEventTime
};
cloudwatchlogs.describeLogStreams(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```